# Powershell - Searching a remote machine for a registry key

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users and the workstations that they login to.  This is how it looks:

```
User1  Workstation1
User1  Workstation2
User2  Workstation3
User3  Workstation1
User4  Workstation6
```

What I need to do now is search that workstation's registry key HKEY_USERS for the SID\Printers\Connections.  The Printers\Connections has subfolders that look like the following ",,Server1,PrintQueue"

In this folder there is a value called Server that is either \server or \server.domain.com

So far I have the following:

```
  #set the workstation I am searching in
  $StrWorkstation = "workstation"
  #this is the value we are looking for
  $str2003Servers="*server*"
  #domain
  $domain = "test"
  #username
  $name="smithj"
  #get the SID
  $strSID = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Domain = 'test'
  AND Name = 'smithj'").SID
  #this is where the key will be
  $StrKeyName="$strSID\Printers\Connections"

  $strRegType = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users
  $strRegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($strRegType,   
  $StrWorkstation)

  $strRegKey = $strRegKey.OpenSubKey($StrKeyName)
```

How can I recursively search either the keys under the Connections folder for *server* or the server value in each key under the Connections key for *server*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change specific registry setting for another user in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999628/how-to-change-specific-registry-setting-for-another-user-in-powershell)

Comment: A worksation (machine) doesn't have an HKCU key; that's relative to the user making the call. Additionally, the specific user's hive is loaded dynamically when the user logs on (it's a file in their profile). This is where the linked duplicate comes in, as it shows how to load that hive. For doing it remotely, I recommend using PowerShell remoting and then treating it like a local registry.

Comment: Sorry I meant the HKEY_USERS which will have the SIDS and the registry entries I believe.

Comment: It only has the SIDs of the users whose hives are loaded though (usually because they are logged on). The hive exists in the user's home directory (`ntuser.dat` I think), and has to be loaded if it's not already.

Comment: I believe HKEY_USERS has the hive for users logged in at some point.  HKCU the current logged on user.

Comment: It's the mount point for users that are currently logged on. Try it out by creating a local user on your machine. Log in once, switch users, check for the loaded SID key under HKU, then log that user out, check again.

Comment: @briantist is right.  The hive is not loaded if the user is not logged in.  I have solved this in the past by mounting a user's `ntuser.dat` file to a temporary hive, done whatever I need to do, and then unmounted it.